# Create HTML Pages at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I paid to a developer to create website for me couple of years ago. Now, I want to replace it with my own website. However, there are some points about his version that I am not able to fully understands.

1. When I check the source files, I can only see a Default.aspx which has only one line and is inherited from "_Default" but I could not find any other ASP pages. My assumption is that all of them were compiled into DLL assemblies however when I publish my own website (using ASP.NET Web Forms and choose to compile into one assembly), I can still see the other ASP pages.
2. When I navigate through his created pages, I cannot see the page names in the address bar but a string similar to

   "?p=PARENTPAGE=2010&txtid=2010" and the PARENTPAGE is the top level menu option.

So, it seems that the pages are created at the run time as even their addresses are not similar to the normal pages.

Sorry, if I am asking amateurish questions, but could anyone tell me how and using what type of web application did they do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think he used a database (like mysql, sql server, etc) to store that "pages", assuming both "PARENTPAGE" and "txtid" are the Ids of the pages.

Comment: Yes they are Ids of same page. So can I do the same using ASP.net web forms?

Comment: You need to know how and where the pages are stored. After this you can write your own code to read and show the pages

Comment: I do not want to use the their pages. I just want to know the method they used and then apply it to my own pages.